# Xcode (version 12.5.1) simulator not navigating past certain pages in my Xamarin Forms application

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, xamarin.forms, ios-simulator

The Xcode simulator (12.5.1) does not navigate past certain pages in my Xamarin forms application. The pages are navigated correctly when tested on a physical device, such as iPhone or iPad. This issue hasn't been occurring only until recently; to be more specific after all the iOS updates that have been going around. Any idea why this happens?

UPDATE: This only occurs when I set it to Debug|iPhoneSimulator, it does not happen when I set it to Release|iPhoneSimulator.

Comment: Xocde has supported iOS15 , could you update it to `Xcode 13` to see if problem persists ?

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT It works fine after updating. Thank you.